# How can I set authentication options for an azure container app via Python SDK?

Tags: python, azure, active-directory, azure-container-apps

We're using the Python ContainerAppsAPIClient library to deploy a container app to our azure estate, and it works great however I can't find any documentation on how to set the authentication on the container app either during or after it's been created. In the portal it's super easy to do, and there are some models I've found that appear to support it, but I'm not sure what other model I need to inject them into (if any?).

We're creating the ContainerApp in this kind of fashion:

```
container_app = ContainerApp(
    location=container_location,
    tags=tags,
    environment_id=f"/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{shared_infra_resource_group_name}/providers/Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments/{container_app_environment}",
    configuration=Configuration(
        active_revisions_mode="Single",
        secrets=secrets_config,
        registries=[registry_credentials],
        ingress=ingress,
    ),
    template=template,
    identity=identity,
)
```

Posible models I've found to use were: `AzureActiveDirectoryLogin`, `AuthConfig` etc. but no idea where to put them.. the documentation is pretty much non-existent around this.

More specifically we want to put the container app being our azure active directory login (on the same subscription), using the SDK. Below shows what I did manually in the portal that I'd like to recreate using the SDK:

[image: A screenshot of the azure portal]

I've tried the following code:

```
client.container_apps_auth_configs.create_or_update(
        resource_group_name=resource_group_name,
        container_app_name=container_app_name,
        auth_config_name="current", # Code: AuthConfigInvalidName. Message: The name 'label-studio' is disallowed for authconfigs, please use the name 'current'.
        auth_config_envelope=AuthConfig(
            platform=AuthPlatform(
                enabled=True
            ),
            global_validation=GlobalValidation(
                unauthenticated_client_action="Return401"
            ), # Some more settings for Auth if you want 'em
            identity_providers=IdentityProviders(
                azure_active_directory=AzureActiveDirectory(
                    enabled=True,
                    registration=AzureActiveDirectoryRegistration(
                        open_id_issuer="https://sts.windows.net/REDACTED-UUID/v2.0" # The azure AD app registration uri
                    ),
                    login=AzureActiveDirectoryLogin(),

                )
            ),
            login=Login(),
            http_settings=HttpSettings()
        )
    )
```

Except that this results in the portal showing this on the auth page:

```
All traffic is blocked, and requests will receive an HTTP 401 Unauthorized. This is because there is an authentication requirement, but no identity provider is configured. Click 'Remove authentication' to disable this feature and remove the access restriction. Or click 'Add identity provider' to configure a way for clients to authenticate themselves.
```

No idea why as it looks like I did provide an identity provider

Comment: Have you associated the auth config to your container app? @John Hunt

Comment: @Jahnavi that is what I'm trying to do with the code above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I ran your code in my environment, I too got **same error** in Portal as below:

[image]

> In my case, adding **Microsoft** as identity provider worked when I included **existing** application `clientId` and `secret` in Python code.

For that, you can register one Azure AD application with **Redirect URI** as `<container-app-url>/.auth/login/aad/callback` like this:

[image]

Now, create one **client secret** in above app and add that secret **value** in Container app `Secret` tab:

[image]

When I ran below modified code by including `client ID` and `secret` of existing app, I got **response** like this:

```py
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.appcontainers import ContainerAppsAPIClient

def main():
    client = ContainerAppsAPIClient(
        credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
        subscription_id="sub_id",
    )

    response = client.container_apps_auth_configs.create_or_update(
        resource_group_name="Sri",
        container_app_name="containerapp04",
        auth_config_name="current",
        auth_config_envelope={
            "properties": {
                "globalValidation": {"unauthenticatedClientAction": "Return401"},
                "identityProviders": {
                    "azureActiveDirectory": {"enabled": True, "isAutoProvisioned": True,"login": {},"registration": {"clientId": "appId","clientSecretSettingName": "secret","openIdIssuer": "https://sts.windows.net/tenantId/v2.0"}, "validation":{"allowedAudiences":["appId"]}}
                },
                "platform": {"enabled": True},
            }
        },
    )
    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal where **Microsoft** is configured as identity provider successfully in container app:

[image]

When I clicked on **`Edit`** option, I got below screen with identity provider properties:

[image]

**Reference:**
[Create or Update Auth Config in Azure Container App using Python SDK · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/appcontainers/azure-mgmt-appcontainers/generated_samples/auth_configs_create_or_update.py)

Comment: I've managed to get that to work, but how can I create an app registration using the SDK?

Comment: Will update the answer soon once I find that option. Currently, doing trial and error to achieve that!

Comment: Thanks, this answer seems to answer what I asked for. We decided to register the app in a different area where we use terraform due to the client secrets expiring where we have something in place to refresh that.